# C++ undefined reference for libtins library

Tags: c++, cmake, static-libraries

I installed the `libtins` package for C++, by building it as described and adding `#include <tins/tins.h>` to the header of the example file. I ran `ldconfig` but building always throws a Undefined reference error:

```
CMakeFiles/lts.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `main':
/home/patrick/ClionProjects/lts/main.cpp:6: undefined reference to `Tins::EthernetII::EthernetII(Tins::HWAddress<6ul, unsigned char> const&, Tins::HWAddress<6ul, unsigned char> const&)'
/home/patrick/ClionProjects/lts/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Tins::IPv4Address::IPv4Address(char const*)'
/home/patrick/ClionProjects/lts/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Tins::IPv4Address::IPv4Address(char const*)'
/home/patrick/ClionProjects/lts/main.cpp:7: undefined reference to `Tins::IP::IP(Tins::IPv4Address, Tins::IPv4Address)'
/home/patrick/ClionProjects/lts/main.cpp:8: undefined reference to `Tins::TCP::TCP(unsigned short, unsigned short)'
/home/patrick/ClionProjects/lts/main.cpp:10: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::inner_pdu(Tins::PDU*)'
/home/patrick/ClionProjects/lts/main.cpp:12: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::inner_pdu(Tins::PDU*)'
CMakeFiles/lts.dir/main.cpp.o: In function `Tins::EthernetII::~EthernetII()':
/usr/local/include/tins/ethernetII.h:46: undefined reference to `vtable for Tins::EthernetII'
/usr/local/include/tins/ethernetII.h:46: undefined reference to `Tins::PDU::~PDU()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [lts] Error 1
```

I am using [CLion](https://www.jetbrains.com/clion/) as IDE and the following cmake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(lts)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -ltins")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)

add_executable(lts ${SOURCE_FILES})
```

Any Idea what could be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a couple of things to address in your question. First, let CMake find the location of the libtins library for you, then use `target_link_libraries()` to add it to your `lts` executable. In the CMake sample in your question, you are specifying library options in the compiler flags variable (CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS). The other thing is to also let CMake handle setting the appropriate compiler flags for C++11 instead of manually adding them to CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS (which would only take care of the compiler part but not the linker). The following should do what you want in a robust, platform independent way:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

project(lts)

find_library(TINS_LIBRARY tins)

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(lts ${SOURCE_FILES})

target_link_libraries(lts "${TINS_LIBRARY}")
```

I recommend you read the CMake docs for [find_library()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/find_library.html) and [target_link_libraries()](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/target_link_libraries.html) to understand what those commands do. For the C++11 stuff, I recommend [this blog article](https://crascit.com/2015/03/28/enabling-cxx11-in-cmake/) for a more cohesive explanation than what the CMake docs give you (disclosure: I wrote the article).

Answer (score 2):

The CMake variable `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` is for the *compiler* flags, not for libraries.

To add a library you should use [`target_link_libraries`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/command/target_link_libraries.html):

```
target_link_libraries(lts tins)
```

If you want *all* targets to link to the same library, you should add it to the list [`CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_STANDARD_LIBRARIES.html).

---

A small tip on debugging these kind of things: Either set [`CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/variable/CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE.html?highlight=verbose) or use `make VERBOSE=1` to inhibit the normal CMake build output, and instead display the normal `make` output, which will show you all commands `make` runs, and all flags and options used for each and every program. That way you will be able to see the `-ltins` flag being passed as a compiler flag, but not as a linker flag or library.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler should `-ltins`. Refer to CMake manual on how to add library dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Download](http://libtins.github.io/download/#using) page of libtins:

> In order to link your application with libtins on GCC or clang, use the -ltins flag

Simply add the following line in your CMake file:

```
target_link_libraries(PROJECT_NAME -ltins)
```

Comment: This is essentially a repeat of Craig Scott's answer above.