# CMake noobie problems: trying to compile Libtins example

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, vcpkg

I'm trying to get my Libtins test project built with Vcpkg and CMake using CLion, but I'm having problems and this is the output from CLion:

```
====================[ Build | libtins | Debug ]=================================
/snap/clion/237/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake --build /home/laptop/dev/testing/libtins/cmake-build-debug --target libtins -j 10
ninja: error: unknown target 'libtins'
```

This is my `CMakeLists.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.25)
project(main)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

find_package(libtins CONFIG REQUIRED)

add_executable(main main.cpp)

# Libtins
target_link_libraries(main PRIVATE tins)
```

And my `main.cpp` file:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tins/tins.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Tins;

int main() {
    std::vector<Packet> vt;

    Sniffer sniffer("wlp1s0");
    while (vt.size() != 10) {
        // next_packet returns a PtrPacket, which can be implicitly converted to Packet.
        vt.push_back(sniffer.next_packet());
    }
    // Done, now let's check the packets
    for (const auto& packet : vt) {
        // Is there an IP PDU somewhere?
        if (packet.pdu()->find_pdu<IP>()) {
            // Just print timestamp's seconds and IP source address
            std::cout << "At: " << packet.timestamp().seconds()
                      << " - " << packet.pdu()->rfind_pdu<IP>().src_addr()
                      << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Yes, I am a complete CMake noob but I want to at least get the example compiled before I give up... So any help would be appreciated.

1. Created new CLion CMake C++ project
2. Pasted the code example
3. Enabled Vcpkg in CLion
4. Installed libtins via the Vcpkg CLion GUI
5. Pressed "Add packages to CMakeLists.txt" in CLion, pasted it in the CMakeLists.txt, and got the error.

Update: Created new project with new name which was not "libtins", and received the following error:

```
====================[ Build | libtins_testing | Debug ]=========================
/snap/clion/237/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake --build /home/laptop/dev/testing/libtins-testing/cmake-build-debug --target libtins_testing -j 10
[0/1] Re-running CMake...
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "libtins" with any
  of the following names:

    libtinsConfig.cmake
    libtins-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "libtins" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libtins_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libtins" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/laptop/dev/testing/libtins-testing/cmake-build-debug/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
FAILED: build.ninja 
/snap/clion/237/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake --regenerate-during-build -S/home/laptop/dev/testing/libtins-testing -B/home/laptop/dev/testing/libtins-testing/cmake-build-debug
ninja: error: rebuilding 'build.ninja': subcommand failed
```

Comment: libtins exports the target [`tins`](https://github.com/mfontanini/libtins/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L327). Where does `--target libtins` come from?

Comment: @273K I don't know, but I renamed the project file in the CMake file, because the original project name was just "libtins" which I thought would conflict with the actual library. I created a new project I received a new error. Will update question.

Comment: Remove `--target libtins` as that target does not exist.

Comment: Yes thanks @JohnHanley I've created a new project without the name "libtins" now, but I get the error I have added to the question.

Comment: Show the command you used to install libtins using vcpkg. Make sure you have specified the correct triplet.

Comment: Did not use a command, used CLion GUI. Pressed install, it installed triplet "libtins-x64-linux". Then pressed "Add packages to CMakeList.txt" and placed the two (find_package and target_link_libraries) commands in the file.

Comment: The error is that the package libtins cannot be found. Try using this `find_package(libtins REQUIRED)` in CMakeLists.txt.

Comment: @JohnHanley Thanks, but I already have that in my CMakeLists.txt. My CMake file is in my question.

Comment: No you don't. Reread the exact command in my comment.

Comment: Removing the CONFIG made no difference.

Comment: I think the output is telling you everything you need to know:   `Add the installation prefix of "libtins" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "libtins_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "libtins" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.` libtins has a CMake folder. Make sure your call to cmake has the path to that folder specified (e.g. by setting `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` or `libtins_DIR` to that path). Otherwise configure won't have the instructions.

Comment: The above comment does not take into account CLion. I don't know how it interfaces with cmake, but somehow, you need to tell cmake to look for that libtins/cmake directory.

Comment: I tried PcapPlusPlus and that workes like a charm doing exactly the same as I've done with libtins! Idk if it's a problem with libtins and vcpkg...?

Comment: "Removing the CONFIG made no difference." - It should made the difference at least for the **error message**. Without CONFIG the error message should start with "By not providing Findlibtins.cmake". BTW, the command line `/snap/clion/237/bin/cmake/linux/x64/bin/cmake --regenerate-during-build -S/home/laptop/dev/testing/libtins-testing -B/home/laptop/dev/testing/libtins-testing/cmake-build-debug` has no trace of enabled vcpkg. It smells like you haven't enabled it actually...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C++ undefined reference for libtins library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36670466/c-undefined-reference-for-libtins-library)

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong/interesting about the way libtins is configured for Vcpkg, so I needed to add this additional line above the standard `target_link_libraries` statements:

```
target_include_directories(LibtinsTest PRIVATE ${LIBTINS_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```